# Pandas: Article category prediction performance slow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, bayesian

I'm working on a naive multinomial bayes classifier for articles in Pandas and have run into a bit of an issue with performance. My repo is here if you want the full code and the dataset I'm using: https://github.com/kingcodefish/multinomial-bayesian-classification/blob/master/main.ipynb

Here's my current setup with two dataframes: `df` for the articles with lists of tokenized words and `word_freq` to store precomputed frequency and P(word | category) values.

```py
for category in df['category'].unique():
    category_filter = word_freq.loc[word_freq['category'] == category]
    cat_articles = df.loc[df['category'] == category].shape[0] # The number of categorized articles
    p_cat = cat_articles / df.shape[0] # P(Cat) = # of articles per category / # of articles
    df[category] = df['content'].apply(lambda x: category_filter[category_filter['word'].isin(x)]['p_given_cat'].prod()) * p_cat
```

Example data:

**df**

```
        category                                            content
0   QUEER VOICES  [online, dating, thoughts, first, date, grew, ...
1        COLLEGE  [wishes, class, believe, generation, better, j...
2       RELIGION  [six, inspiring, architectural, projects, revi...
3       WELLNESS  [ultramarathon, runner, micah, true, died, hea...
4  ENTERTAINMENT  [miley, cyrus, ball, debuts, album, art, cyrus...
```

**word_freq**

```
           category         word  freq  p_given_cat
46883         MEDIA         seat   1.0     0.333333
14187         CRIME         ends   1.0     0.333333
81317    WORLD NEWS         seat   1.0     0.333333
12463        COMEDY       living   1.0     0.200000
20868     EDUCATION     director   1.0     0.500000
```

Please note that the `word_freq` table is a cross product of the categories x words, so every word appears once and only once in each category, so the table does contain duplicates. Also, the `freq` column has been increased by 1 to avoid zero values (Laplace smoothed).

After running the above, I do this to find the max category P (each category's P is stored in a column after its name) and get the following:

```py
df['predicted_category'] = df[df.columns.difference(['category', 'content'])].idxmax(axis=1)
df = df.drop(df.columns.difference(['category', 'content', 'predicted_category']), axis=1).reset_index(drop = True)
```

```
          category                                            content  \
0         POLITICS  [bernie, sanders, campaign, split, whether, fi...   
1           COMEDY  [bill, maher, compares, police, unions, cathol...   
2         WELLNESS  [busiest, people, earth, find, time, relax, th...   
3    ENTERTAINMENT  [lamar, odom, gets, standing, ovation, first, ...   
4            GREEN                      [lead, longer, life, go, gut]   
   predicted_category  
0                ARTS  
1                ARTS  
2                ARTS  
3               TASTE  
4               GREEN
```

This method seems to work well, but it is unfortunately really slow. I am using a large dataset of 200,000 articles with short descriptions and operating on only 1% of this is taking almost a minute. I know it's because I am looping through the categories instead of relying on vectorization, but I am very very new to Pandas and trying to formulate this in a `groupby` succinctly escapes me (especially with the two data tables, also might be unnecessary), so I'm looking for suggestions here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone happens to come across this later...

Instead of representing my categories x words as a cross product of every possible word of every category, which inflated to over 3 million rows in my data set, I decided to reduce them to only the necessary ones per category and provide a default value for ones that did not exist, which ended up being about 600k rows.

But the biggest speedup came from changing to the following:

```py
for category in df['category'].unique():
    # Calculate P(Category)
    category_filter = word_freq.loc[word_freq['category'] == category]
    cat_articles = df.loc[df['category'] == category].shape[0]
    p_cat = cat_articles / df.shape[0]
    
    # Create a word->P(word | category) dictionary for quick lookups
    category_dict = category_filter.set_index('word').to_dict()['p_given_cat']
    
    # For every article, find the product of P(word | category) values of the words, then multiply by P(category) to get bayes.
    df[category] = df['content'].apply(lambda x: np.prod([category_dict.get(y, 0.001 / (cat_articles + 0.001)) for y in x])) * p_cat
```

I created a dictionary from the two columns `word` and the P(word | category) as the key-value respectively. This reduced the problem to a quick dictionary lookup for each element of each list and computing that product.

This ended up being about 100x faster, parsing the whole dataset in ~40 seconds.